# Instagram fetch all comments

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I have implemented Instagram api's in my app. And showing all media's and comments in custom layout of IOS app.

I'm using `http://api/instagram.com/{media_ id}/comments/` GET api to fetch all comments under that media. I have more than 500 comments under that media but showing only recent 150 comments.

can anybody help me to how to fetch all comments using endpoints and add pagination in my app??

Thanks in advance. Looking forward for reply.

Comment: What about the `comments` property in the `Media` Object itself? Calling `media/{media_id}` should give you the `Media` Object. In that Object there lies a `comments` Object, which has a `count` attribute. What does it say?

Answer (score 2):

According to New Instagram API documentation you **can not** get more than 150 comments by Instagram API or `scrapping`  or also in web version.you can try web version of Instagram and push load more comments, but finally you'll find out you just can see 150 comments.